# Reports don't get displayed in browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I try  SQL Reporting Services in Visual Studio 2008 using SQL Server 2008 R2..

When I deploy the report in browser ,it cannot show me any report
here is the image

[image](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/393283)

How do I display the report?

Comment: That looks like it's using SQL Express, not 2008 R2. I didn't know SSRS could do that!

Comment: i have sql server 2008 r2

Comment: OK, but the URL in the image is for SQLExpress

Comment: please go this link i also discuss probelm here ...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/faca2bb5-d799-40fd-979c-307c147a86c5/sql-reporting-username-and-password?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: So did you do what Faisal Muhammed said, change the Deploy url in your project?

Comment: yes i do .... but when i dont know why it cannot display the reports

Comment: I think you might need to read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365166(v=SQL.105).aspx - when using SQL Express (even 2008 R2) you have some limitations.

Comment: ok when i use localhost and then i click on deploy it show me enter username and password but i dont have a password in windows  in sql server ...

Comment: Last time\: have you changed the TargetServerUrl in your project to https://localhost/ReportServer_SQLExpress2 ? Did it deploy then? Did you read the link I gave above about configuring SSRS when using SQLExpress? That has info about how to give permissions.

Comment: yes i read and in article they say that use localhost in reortmanager and when i use localhost/ReportServer_SQLExpress2 last time and then click deploy it always show me enter username and password

Comment: Can you even browse to the Report Server home page? Also reports are usually deployed to servername/reportserver but viewed at servername/Reports

Comment: how i browse report server home page?